# How to insert data on MongoDB first which includes the message id of a message that is about to be created, discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

Here's what I need to do:

1. User uses a discord command that generates a new message.
2. Get the message id of a message that will be created.
3. Then insert data to MongoDB with the message ID.
4. Once data is inserted to db, send the new message.

I only want the message to show once the insert to database is a success. I'm not sure how to get the id of a new message that is not yet sent. Does that make sense?

Here's my code currently:

```
if (command === "generatemessage") {
    db.collection("doc").insertOne({newMessageId: "", title: "This is new"}) //empty message id, my problem
    .then(async() => {
        if (insert is success) {
            const msg = await client.channels.cache.get(channelId).send("This is a new msg"); //get the new msg id here
            console.log(msg.id) //outputs msg id
        }
    })
}
```

I can do it like this instead but this is not what I want because this will show the message regardless if the insert to db is not successful:

```
if (command === "generatemessage") {
    client.channels.cache.get(channelId).send("This is the new message!").then((msg) => {
    db.collection("doc").insertOne({newMessageId: msg.id, title: "This is new"})
    }
})
```

Comment: How does `message.channel.send` generate the id?

Comment: @Joe, I edited it. Sorry about that